# Write console output to .txt AND show it on console

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console, output, prompt

I recently discovered that you can save the console output from a C++ program to a text file using Visual Studio (adding a "> output.txt" in Command Arguments on your project properties).

The problem is that I want the output to show both inside the output file I create and the command console, for easier debugging (once you save the output to a file, it doesn't show anymore on the console). Is there any option to enable both of these features in Visual Studio, or something similar?

Comment: Take a look at what `tee` does.

Comment: You best bet is to write a small logger that writes to both `cout` and the file you want to save the output in.

Comment: Since I already have a pretty big code I was looking forward to not having to alter it further, that's why I'm looking at the moment for VS alternatives for this.

Comment: is [Boost::IOStreams](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) an option? you could redirect `cout` then to a custom stream writer (i.e. sink), which writes to both a file and the console.

Comment: In the time it'll probably take you to figure out how to do this on Microsoft Windows, you'll probably be able to learn Linux, where this problem was solved about 30 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve sending data to multiple destinations upon output using a custom stream. These are easy to create by creating a suitable stream buffer. For example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <streambuf>

class teebuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    std::streambuf* d_sbuf1;
    std::streambuf* d_sbuf2;
public:
    teebuf(std::streambuf* sbuf1, std::streambuf* sbuf2)
        : d_sbuf1(sbuf1), d_sbuf2(sbuf2) {
    }
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            this->d_sbuf1->sputc(c);
            this->d_sbuf2->sputc(c);
        }
        return std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::ofstream   out("foo.txt");
    teebuf          tb{out.rdbuf(), std::cout.rdbuf()};
    std::streambuf* coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(&tb);
    std::cout << "hello world! (to both the console and the file)\n";

    std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf); // needs to be replaced as it gets used to flush
}
```

Of course, this is an intrusive approach which requires that the source is being changed. I don't use MSVC++ and can't comment on whether there is an approach saving the standard output to a file.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by using command [tee](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html)

Assuming you have an executable ( does not matter if it is implemented in C++ or not) named **myExe**, you can do the following:

```
./myExec | tee output.txt
```

If you want to achieve this in Visual Studio, change `> output.txt` with one of the followings

**1. Working on Linux:**

`| tee output.txt`

**2. Working on Windows:**

`> output.txt && type output.txt`

Comment: Not using VS, which is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look again @Bruno Demantova, thanks for your warning Neil Bluetterworth

Comment: This does not work on Windows. You end up with no output to the console as it has been redirected to a file named `type` in the current working directory. Your new linux instructions are suspect too as normally you would use `|` not `>` to pipe the output to tee.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I updated my answer but not sure if windows version works because  I am not able to test it on windows currently. Thanks @RetiredNinja

Comment: Unfortunately the "> output.txt && type output.txt" line didn't work on Windows. I got the same result as before (just as @RetiredNinja said).

Comment: PowerShell  supports tee BTW.